# Convert disk-installed system to USB multiboot

Tags: live-usb, multiboot

OK, so here's the idea: I have an OS (Debian-based) installed on PCs disk. I would like to convert it somehow to I can use it on a multiboot USB pendrive. How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to decide on the number of partitions you can use on the multiboot pendrive. If you can have at least one Linux-specific partition, you can use a native Linux filesystem on it, which makes things a lot simpler. Also, can the contents of the pendrive stay static once you've built it, or do you need to e.g. make persistent changes to the pendrive installation's `/etc`, for example?

You'll need to make sure your initramfs includes all the kernel modules required to access the pendrive and the filesystem(s) on it, and decide on which bootloader you're going to use. The choice of bootloader may affect where on the pendrive you'll place the kernel and initramfs files: they'll need to be somewhere the bootloader can access them.

Once you have your partition(s) initialized on the pendrive, you can copy your existing filesystem structure on the pendrive, modify the copied `/etc/fstab` on the pendrive to refer to the pendrive's partition(s) instead of the original installation's, place the kernel and initramfs files to where they need to be, and configure the bootloader on the pendrive to include a boot option for the pendrive-based copy of the installation.

If the pendrive needs to be FAT32-only, you will probably have to implement an image-file-based solution, which means at least writing a small custom initramfs script to run `losetup` for the image file that contains your root filesystem before mounting it, in addition to what I outlined above. If you wish to compress the filesystem image file, and need a way to perform persistent modifications on it, that probably means filesystem overlays and further customization.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite extensive description!